# Parse out commas in access search form

Tags: ms-access

I have a search form setup in access with the code to search for keywords, the code is:

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![Search_Form]![KW_Text] & "*"
```

I would like to be able to type in multiple keywords in the search so it pulls up multiple results, as of now if I type in the word "Manager" It returns all the results with the word Manager. I would like to be able to type in Manager, Supervisor and have it return all results with manager and/or supervisor. Any ideas?